# Firebase hosting randomly shows "Site Not Found" at custom domain

Tags: node.js, firebase, dns, firebase-hosting

We recently launched our firebase application at https://tnb-widgets.firebaseapp.com/ and https://thenextbid.com/ (the last one being our custom domain). It all works smoothly except for some seemingly random moments in which it shows a page stating "Site Not Found". This already happened multiple times and after a couple of minutes the site seems to be back again.

The last time this happened was at 2:37AM GMT-5 and the last time I deployed a new release to this same firebase hosting project was at 3:45PM the day before. This release also contained 80 files in total, so it cannot possibly be "an empty directory".

Our firebase.json file looks like this:

```
{
  "firestore": {
    "rules": "firestore.rules",
    "indexes": "firestore.indexes.json"
  },
  "hosting": {
    "public": "build",
    "ignore": [
      "firebase.json",
      "**/.*",
      "**/node_modules/**"
    ],
    "rewrites": [
      {
        "source": "/api/**",
        "function": "app"
      },
      {
        "source": "**",
        "destination": "/index.html"
      }
    ]
  },
  "storage": {
    "rules": "storage.rules"
  }
}
```

There's no service workers registered. The "build" folder contains 80 files and most importantly it contains the "index.html" at its root.

Does anyone have similar issues? I would appreciate any idea to solve this! Thanks.

[image]

Comment: Given the sporadic nature of the problem and the fact it seems to "auto repair", it seems unlikely we can do much here. I recommend you [reach out to Firebase support](https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/troubleshooting/) for personalized help in troubleshooting.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen thanks for your comment. They are looking into it right now. Once that process has any result I will post it in here :)

Comment: @Prutser So? resolved? what was it?

Comment: @MosesSchwartz sorry for the late response: I ended up switching to App Engine. The administrators from Firebase looked into it and they didn't find any solution either. Some code rewrite was required to make the switch, but overall it was very much compatible (both are Google Cloud). This has been a very reliable solution ever since.

Comment: Thanks, I’ll look into it

Comment: This question is answered here https://stackoverflow.com/a/61822161/8939573