# Firebase Custom Domain Showing "Site Not Found"

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

I have verified the Domain Name
Also, have linked the A records
It's been 24 Hour's since the changes have been made to DNS Records
Yet the screen remains same

The app works perfectly on Firebase Default Domain.
[image: image of error from firebase]

Comment: Hi, in your firebase console (https://console.firebase.google.com/u/0/project/{{PROJECT_NAME}}/hosting/main), does it show the custom domain as "Connected"?

Comment: It shows 'Need Setup"

Comment: I moved from Quick Setup to Advance Setup added an extra .txt file to DNS and setup was done in few secs.

Answer (score 10):

If anyone comes here this might help. 
Usually, it happens because of some kind of error during picking DNS info between the 'www.example.com' and the 'example.com'. What worked for me, is to delete the domain from the firebase console and to reconnect it back. Don't change anything on your DNS provider if everything is set correctly.

Note: This is when your domain status shows connected but you still experience the "Site not found" error

If you have problems connecting your domain, some DNS providers use "@" instead of "www.example.com" and some simply use "example.com"

Comment: To add to the answer, if you link `www.yourdomain.com`, Firebase will automatically ask you whether you want to redirect `yourdomain.com` to `www.yourdomain.com`

Comment: Deleting and re-adding domain in firebase worked for me, although it took some time to take effect